# Find download URL from datatables "CSV" button?

Tags: shiny, dt

[This R Shiny application](https://metrotransitmn.shinyapps.io/metc-wastewater-covid-monitor/) appears to use [`DT`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch9jGm.png) to display its tables.  At least in the source code I see:

```
<script src="plotly-binding-4.10.0/plotly.js"></script>
<link href="datatables-css-0.0.0/datatables-crosstalk.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="datatables-binding-0.20/datatables.js"></script>
<link href="crosstalk-1.2.0/css/crosstalk.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="crosstalk-1.2.0/js/crosstalk.min.js"></script>
```

It also has a "CSV" button to download the data:

[image: download buttons]

How do I download the data from this website myself without clicking?  I suppose the button runs some javascript, which makes a network call, but the "network" tab of the chrome debugger doesn't show any activity.

Ideally I could find a URL to the data, and then I could use the language of my choice (e.g., wget, curl, python, ..).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the raw data are coming from here via the project github. Seems like `git pull` could do it for you pretty easily.

https://github.com/Metropolitan-Council/covid-poops/blob/main/R/d_covid_cases.R

```
https://static.usafacts.org/public/data/covid-19/covid_confirmed_usafacts.csv?_ga=2.86006619.233414847.1642517751-2016304881.1642174657
```

And the other data are in this repo.

https://github.com/Metropolitan-Council/covid-poops/tree/main/data

I was able to use the python requests library to pull the raw data.

```
import requests

x = requests.get('https://static.usafacts.org/public/data/covid-19/covid_confirmed_usafacts.csv?_ga=2.86006619.233414847.1642517751-2016304881.1642174657')

print(x.text)
```

Edit: It looks like the shiny data are coming from here. I would just grab them via git. The github readme states, "The Shiny app is located in ./metc-wastewater-covid-monitor. /data contains relevant CSV data and /www contains CSS, HTML, and relevant font files the app needs upon running."

https://github.com/Metropolitan-Council/covid-poops/tree/main/metc-wastewater-covid-monitor/data

Comment: Thanks, this is a good suggestion. I appreciate it. However, there is no guarantee that the data showing on the page is the data in github. They are loosely connected. I was hoping for something that would help get the data from the page itself.

Comment: For example, I think perhaps this gets case data without getting the wastewater viral load data.

Comment: I edited my answer based upon your comments.

Comment: FWIW, I got connected with the authors of the page, and they said the same: get the data from github. Also, they mentioned that git has URLs specifically for raw content, e.g., https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Metropolitan-Council/covid-poops/main/metc-wastewater-covid-monitor/data/clean_load_data.csv.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script to use a headerless browser to navigate to the page and download the file.  [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev) is the usual first choice for this kind of work.

Comment: Yes, this is a good suggestion. I thought of this as well. I wish there were an easier way, but maybe there isn't.

Comment: It isn't too difficult.  The main challenge is maintaining this over time since their website may change without notice.